# Make javascript reference variable a value variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, reference

I have a javascript function that goes something like this:

```
function doSomething(me) {
        var isMeChecked = me.checked;
        for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
            me.checked = !isMeChecked;
            alert (me.checked);
        }
    }
```

I assumed that `isMeChecked` would remain constant after the first load, but it apparently is a reference variable to `me.checked`, and so it changes with every iteration.
How do I force `isMeChecked` to get set to the value of `me.checked` when it's first loaded, and not the reference of `me.checked`?

Alright, to make this more clear, I am editing this post to show actual code in use that is exhibiting the undesirable behavior:

Here are the javascript functions:

```
function CheckAll(me, gridViewId) {
    var isMeChecked = (me.checked)?true:false;
    alert('CheckAllFired_1');
    Parent = document.getElementById(gridViewId);
    for (i = 0; i < Parent.rows.length; i++) {
        alert('CheckAllFired_2_' + i.toString());
        var tr = Parent.rows[i];
        var td = tr.childNodes[0];
        var item = td.firstChild;
        if (item.id != me.id && item.type == "checkbox") {
            alert('CheckAllFired_3_' + i.toString() + '_' + me.checked + '_' + isMeChecked);
            item.checked = !isMeChecked;
            item.click();
        }
    }
}
function CheckSelectAll(me, checkBoxHeaderId, gridViewId) {
    alert('CheckSelectAllFired_1');
    if (!me.checked) {
        alert('CheckSelectAllFired_2');
        document.getElementById(checkBoxHeaderId).checked = false;
        return;
    }
    else {
        alert('CheckSelectAllFired_3');
        document.getElementById(checkBoxHeaderId).checked = true;
        Parent = document.getElementById(gridViewId);
        for (i = 0; i < Parent.rows.length; i++) {
            alert('CheckSelectAllFired_4_' + i.toString());
            var tr = Parent.rows[i];
            var td = tr.childNodes[0];
            var item = td.firstChild;
            if (item.type == "checkbox") {
                alert('CheckSelectAllFired_5_' + i.toString());
                if (!item.checked) {
                    alert('CheckSelectAllFired_6_' + i.toString());
                    document.getElementById(checkBoxHeaderId).checked = false;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

I have an asp.net gridview.  The first column is a column of checkboxes, with a checkbox in the header as well that toggles "Select/Deselect All" of the other checkboxes in the column.
The checkbox in the header has it's onclick event set to `onclick="CheckAll(this, 'myGridViewClientID')"`

All of the remaining checkboxes in the grid, have their onlick event set to `onclick="CheckSelectAll(this, 'headerCheckBoxID', 'myGridViewClientID'"`

Both the `headerCheckBoxID` and `myGridViewClientID` are set in the codebehind when the gridview is rendering.

The idea is that when the checkbox in the header is checked, it will set all the other checkboxes to the opposite checked status, and then fire their click event to simulate a click, and also fire their onclick actions (which involve things like changing the color of their row, setting the datakey of the row into a SelectedValues array if it is checked, etc).

However, I also wanted the child checkboxes to have the following behavior:
1) If any of them get unchecked, uncheck the "select all" checkbox.
2) If all of them get checked, check the "select all" checkbox.

Now, because the click event of the child checkboxes has the opportunity to change the checked status of the headercheckbox, when the loop returns back to the "checkall" event, the state of the headercheckbox is different than when it first started, and so it ends up only checking the first child checkbox when trying to do a select all.

Using alerts, I was able to see that when the checked state of the headercheckbox is changed in the CheckSelectAll function, that value is also changed for the "isMeChecked" value in the CheckAll function which is spawning the CheckSelectAll functions.

That looks an awful lot like a reference variable then. I don't know how to stop it from doing that.

Comment: What's your question? isMeChecked is not a reference to me.checked, your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Something's wrong with your example code.  Assuming I pass in {checked: true} as the argument to doSomething, I get the exact same value alerted every time.  Also, what is me.checked != isMeChecked supposed to do?  It's a useless statement right now, assuming checked isn't a setter that has side effects.

Comment: I was writing the code from memory so it had a typo.  I changed "me.checked != isMeChecked" to "me.checked = !isMeChecked" which is what I actually have in the real sample I'm working with.

In the real code, I have a checkbox which has an onclick event that calls a function.  The function sets the checked status of several other checkboxes on the page to the opposite value of the original checkbox and then calls the onclick event for those checkboxes.
The onclick event for the children checkboxes sometimes changes the checked value of the parent checkbox, which was then messing up the loop.

Comment: really, `isMeChecked=(me.checked)?true:false` IS nonsense. see comments below.

Comment: "When the checked state of the header checkbox is changed in the CheckSelectAll function, that value is also changed for the "isMeChecked" value in the CheckAll function" - that's because you manually change the value of isMeChecked, right at the top of CheckAll()!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about it. assume x.checked = true. run doSomething(x).
When the function starts, me.checked is true. Now look at your for loop:

Pass 1: me.checked is true. so isMeChecked is true. so you set me.checked to false.

Pass 2: me.checked is false. isMeChecked is still true, because you don't change it inside the loop. so me.checked is again set to false.

Pass 3: see pass 2.
...

When the function exits, isMeChecked is true, and me.checked is false. All you have done is set me.checked to false 10 times.
This is not a matter of isMeChecked being a reference (because it's not), but just an error in your logic if you were expecting different results.

Comment: Well according to my tests, IsMeChecked was being changed when me.checked was changed.  Which is why I assumed it was a reference variable.

Comment: You were probably not doing the right test. It's simple to check. Try this: `var me={checked:true};var isMeChecked=me.checked;isMeChecked=false;alert(me.checked)`. You will see that me.checked is still true even though isMeChecked was set to false.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm crazy, there's no such thing as a reference to a boolean in javascript. They're always passed by value. Can you paste complete example code that we can run without filling in any blanks?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is just broken -- Read the comments

```
// doSomething({checked:true});
function doSomething(me) {
    // isMeChecked = true;
    var isMeChecked = me.checked;
    for (i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        // me.checked = false ... always...
        me.checked = !isMeChecked;
        alert (me.checked);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could do `var isMeChecked = me.checked?true:false;`

Also, `me.checked != isMeChecked` is not the same as `me.checked = !isMeChecked`, which is probably what you intended.

Comment: ah yes, you are correct sir.  I was doing this from memory.  It's something I was working on at the office and didn't have the code right in front of me.  On top of it, I am not a javascript guru by any means, so that adds to the mistakes. =)
I will try your suggestion first thing in the morning.  Thanks!
(fixed the error in the original message)

Comment: me.checked?true:false is nonsense

Comment: Isn't var isMeChecked = (me.checked)?true;false; an example of the "conditional operator" like in C#?

Comment: it is a ternary operator http://javascriptant.com/articles/28/the-conditional-operator-ternary-operactor

Comment: it's nonsense because `isMeChecked = me.checked?true:false` is *exactly* equivalent to `isMeChecked = me.checked`.

Comment: @ithcy : Well that is assuming that me.checked will always be bool.. "test" 1 true {} [] all would set it to true, false 0 and negative numbers would return false. That said, it would only be useful if you need to know if a var is set to anything positive, (true 1+ "string" [] {})..